# Terminate session - IInstanceContextInitializer close with custom statuscode?

Tags: wcf, wcf-security

I have a wcf application and i interest to close the instanceContext session with status of UnAutorized status, currently if i using Abort method - it return me InternalServerError.

It's possible to close with custom statuscode?

Answer (score 1):

I would be more inclined to base on error rather than session's status code. By specifying custom exception you can provide extensive information about the nature of error, including its statusCode.